# How to consolidate output based on highest value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following input where a user watched a program in the following percentages (25 or 50 or 75 or 100).I just want to calculate the highest percentage viewed by a certain user on a certain id.
The inputs and outputs are given below.

Input

```
id1, u1, watched25
id2, u1, watched25
id1, u1, watched50
id1, u1, watched75
id3, u1, watched25
id4, u1, watched25
id1, u1, watched100
id2, u1, watched50
id5, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched50
id5, u1, watched75
id5, u1, watched100
id1, u2, watched25
id1, u2, watched50
id3, u2, watched25
id3, u3, watched25
id1, u2, watched75
id4, u3, watched25
id4, u3, watched50
```

Desired output

```
id1, u1, watched100
id2, u1, watched50
id3, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched25
id5, u1, watched100
id1, u2, watched75
id3, u2, watched25
id3, u3, watched25
id4, u3, watched50
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, user, max(watched)
from tbl
group by id, user
```

I suggest you to change "watchedXX" to "XX" for easier calculations. My query above is based on this assumption

Answer (score 1):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c153/5)**

```
SELECT t1.id1, 
       t1.u1, 
       MAX(CAST(REPLACE(t1.watched25, 'watched', '') AS SIGNED)) as watched
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.id1, t1.u1
```

Result:

```
| ID1 | U1 | WATCHED |
----------------------
| id1 | u1 |     100 |
| id1 | u2 |      75 |
| id2 | u1 |      50 |
| id3 | u1 |      25 |
| id3 | u2 |      25 |
| id3 | u3 |      25 |
| id4 | u1 |      25 |
| id4 | u3 |      50 |
| id5 | u1 |     100 |
```

Desired output query:

```
SELECT t1.id1, 
       t1.u1, 
       CONCAT('watched',MAX(CAST(REPLACE(t1.watched25, 'watched', '') AS SIGNED))) as watched
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.id1, t1.u1
```

Result desired output:

```
| ID1 | U1 |    WATCHED |
-------------------------
| id1 | u1 | watched100 |
| id1 | u2 |  watched75 |
| id2 | u1 |  watched50 |
| id3 | u1 |  watched25 |
| id3 | u2 |  watched25 |
| id3 | u3 |  watched25 |
| id4 | u1 |  watched25 |
| id4 | u3 |  watched50 |
| id5 | u1 | watched100 |
```